# How to add additional properties to "readProperties file"?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

How to inject `key=value` pair to properties read using readProperties from file?

```
...
props = readProperties file: "$parametersFile"
fileParams = props.collect { string(name: it.key, value: it.value) }
build job: "anotherjobName", parameters: fileParams // good, passes parameters read from $parametersFile
fileParams.inject(["EXTRA_PARAM=xparam_value"]) // Is there a way to inject the additional parameter to fileParams, something like this?
build job: "yetAnotherjobName", parameters: fileParams
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it as below:

```
xParam = [ $class: 'StringParameterValue','name': 'EXTRA_PARAM', 'value': "xparam_value" ]
build job: "yetAnotherjobName", parameters: fileParams + xParam
```